# the way to Post or Get the input data to a site in iphone application

Tags: iphone, post

is it possible to Post or Get the input data to a site by using objective C in iphone application,for example in HTML create a form it collect the input data from user and post to the server site

Comment: Not clear what you want here - do you want an iphone/objective C app to use a HTML form to get the user input or post the user input to a web based form...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ASIHTTP http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/